# Error [DF-SA-01] when downloading application from the play store

Tags: downloading

Can anybody help me how can I solve this problem. I have tried options of clearing cache data, force stop google paly store/service, removing google account from accounts and reboting device but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this can be fixed by resetting app preferences:

1. Go to `Settings`> `Apps`
2. Open the menu (usually 3 dots in the top right but may vary depending on your device)
3. Select `Reset app preferences`.

[Source](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/446111-how-do-i-fix-google-play-store-error-df-sa-01-a.html)

Comment: Thanks bmdixon, I have tried but when I press reset button on reset app preferences pop up it just hide pop up and never reset the preference. What can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this (expanding on bmdixon's answer, thanks for your advice!):

1. Go to Settings > Apps > press menu button > Reset app preferences
2. Open Play Store. Open Settings > Apps again, swipe to the "All" view, and find Play Store. Force stop and clear data. Then open Play Store again from the recent apps screen.

Following only step 1 or only step 2 don't help, but together, they seem to work okay.

Answer (score -2):

Settings > Apps > Google Play Store > Uninstall updates. Then restart your device.